# Setting a window's background to an unusual pattern before drawing into it

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a window (`CWnd` object), into which I am drawing a bitmap image.

Before doing so, I would like to set the window's background to a specific pattern.

The pattern may change from time to time.

If I understand correctly, then I need to override the window's `OnCtlColor` function, and return a brush compatible with my desired pattern (recalculated according to internal data-structure).

1. Am I on the right track?
2. The pattern is rather irregular. It consists of "zebra stripes", all of which are of the same width, but (may be) of different heights. Here is an illustrated example:

[image]

Is it even possible to create a brush with such pattern?

If yes, then which of the following functions would be the most appropriate:

- `CBrush::CreateBrushIndirect`
- `CBrush::CreateDIBPatternBrush`
- `CBrush::CreateHatchBrush`
- `CBrush::CreatePatternBrush`

Thank you.

Comment: Also look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx

Comment: @KonstantinL: OK, this is quite a good idea. So this answers my first question, I can just draw my desired pattern at `OnEraseBkgnd`. But right now I know how to do it with `CDC::Rectangle`. Is there any way to easily create a brush and just draw the entire background with it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably this one: CreateDIBPatternBrushPt (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183493(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't even bother with brushes. This example draws a bunch of stripes using FillSolidRect and stripe heights in screen height percentages. Should be easy to adjust if you're using absolutes.

```
BOOL CChildView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect clientRect;
    GetClientRect(clientRect);

    const auto savedDC = pDC->SaveDC();

    // Make the co-ordinates system behave like percentages
    {
        pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
        pDC->SetWindowExt(100, 100);
        pDC->SetViewportExt(clientRect.right, clientRect.bottom);
    }

    // pair requires #include <utility>
    std::pair<int, COLORREF> stripeData[] =
    {
        { 8, RGB(220,220,220) },    // 8% of window height, light grey
        { 17, RGB(165,165,165) },   // 17% of window height, dark grey
        { 12, RGB(220,220,220) },   // etc. These should total 100%
        { 7, RGB(165,165,165) },
        { 23, RGB(220,220,220) },
        { 33, RGB(165,165,165) }
    };

    // NOTE: FillSolidRect changes the background color, so restore it at the
    // end of the function. RestoreDC will handle this; otherwise save the
    // GetBkColor return value and restore it by calling SetBkColor

    //auto oldBkColor = pDC->GetBkColor();

    // Draw the stripes
    CRect stripeRect{0,0,100,0};
    for (auto const& data : stripeData)
    {
        stripeRect.bottom = stripeRect.top + data.first;
        pDC->FillSolidRect(stripeRect, data.second);
        stripeRect.OffsetRect(0, data.first);
    }

    //pDC->SetBkColor(oldBkColor);

    pDC->RestoreDC(savedDC);

    return TRUE;
}
```